# which package file for ca-certificates do I download?

Tags: apt, security, certificates

i have a very old server, hosted at Digital Ocean, running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus), but no time to migrate to a new one.

when I try apt-get updates, it shows the error

> CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

I'm trying to follow https://serverfault.com/questions/1093511/apt-get-update-failing-because-of-certificate-validation to replace all ca-certificates, and it's comments recommends to search the Ubunutu repository to download the correct file for my OS.

at this page: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/?C=M;O=D I find 4 files:

- ca-certificates_20210119~16.04.1_all.deb 2021-02-02 18:18    144K
- ca-certificates-udeb_20210119~16.04.1_all.udeb   2021-02-02 18:18    116K
- ca-certificates_20210119~16.04.1.dsc 2021-02-02 18:18    1.9K
- ca-certificates_20210119~16.04.1.tar.xz  2021-02-02 18:18    226K

Should I pick _all.deb ?

Is that the correct package file to download since it matches my version of Ubuntu?

And I access this server using Putty via SSH. I am concerned that if I try to remove the existing ca-certificates package, and then install it again, will I not be able to use Putty to connect to the server if I remove the ca-certs during the reinstall, or am I misunderstanding ca-certs vs SSH keys?

Thank you...

Comment: You need ESM to update certificates, where the package changes over time.. Do you have ESM *enabled*..   The duplicate answer is now OLD & thus is no longer the correct file, but if you have ESM *enabled* the correct file will be automatically downloaded correctly (*during normal upgrades of packages*)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is *community* support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Answer (score 0):

The package [ca-certificates_20210119~16.04.1_all.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20210119%7E16.04.1_all.deb) seems to be the latest official version for Xenial.  One of my Xenial machines also has this package installed.